# Raspberry Pi Relay control in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, osgi-bundle

I am using a project called powermatcher that is implemented using OSGi (https://github.com/flexiblepower/powermatcher). I am having a hard time understanding the structure of OSGi and how to add to this project.

The idea of powermatcher is that devices can react to price updates. There is an example of a [freezer included](https://github.com/flexiblepower/powermatcher/blob/development/net.powermatcher.examples/src/net/powermatcher/examples/Freezer.java#L130). I will be controlling the power to the freezer with a raspberry pi gpio and relay board. I want the freezer to be able to call `relay.changeState('freezer')` to either open or close the relay for the freezer. Obviously I need multiple other devices to do the same thing.

Should I create another bundle that has an interface for the pi, then implement it within the freezer somehow? Should it be a component, api or declarative service?

Just a rough outline of how to implement this would be greatly appreciated.